# Is Stack Overflow a good place to ask Photoshop questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

Is Stack Overflow a good place to ask Photoshop questions, or is there another site in the Stack Exchange family for those questions?

Comment: Is it about how to use options in Photoshop or is it more trouble shooting? If it's the latter then Super User is definitely the place. If it's the former then Super User is probably OK, but you might get a better response on Photoshop forums.

Comment: @ChrisF: would have been fine as answer imo

Answer (score 17):

Super User may be your best bet, but it depends a lot on what you're doing with Photoshop. I know that Stack Overflow and Server Fault are definitely *not* appropriate.

There are also graphic design (and photography) [sites on Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) which may be a good fit.

Answer (score 15):

Try [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Or [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) if you're doing photo post-processing.

Answer (score 5):

If your question involves programming or automation, then it may be a good candidate for Stack Overflow. Have a look at the [tagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) for examples of what is appropriate.

After looking at those questions, if your question doesn't seem to fit in with them, then Super User would be the best place to ask your question.

Comment: Thank you for the list -- I'd say a good half of the ones there which are still open ought to be closed, most (if not all) of those migrated. Good way to help me use up my remaining close votes for the day. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Ask yourself**: Is my question related to programming in *any* point?

If the answer is **yes**, then a good formulated question that fits the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) guidelines has its place on Stack Overflow.

I think it's possible to imagine a few automation questions about photoshop related to programming. But don't ask about non-programming stuff.

Photoshop itself is **not** programming.

Answer (score -2):

You could also try the [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com) site on Stack Exchange. If the questions are about processing photos, that is.

Otherwise, Super User is the place to go.

Comment: What makes this answer different than [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41927/152859)? You just repeat why he said there three years ago.